# Oracle Syntax to Postgres Help

Tags: sql

I am trying to convert this code from Oracle:

```
CREATE VIEW PLANNED AS
SELECT ASP.ASP_SPACE_NM,
       SUM(MO.MO_TKR_TOTAL_OFF_SCHEDULED) "TOTAL_PLANNED"
  FROM OBJECTIVE MO, SPACE ASP
 WHERE ASP.ASP_SPACE_NM = MO.ASP_SPACE_NM (+)
   AND MO.MO_MSN_CLASS_NM = 'EPIC'
 GROUP BY ASP.ASP_SPACE_NM
```

To Postgres.

Two lines in this are confusing me:

```
   SUM(MO.MO_TKR_TOTAL_OFF_SCHEDULED) "TOTAL_PLANNED"
```

Is this the same as this?

```
   SUM(MO.MO_TKR_TOTAL_OFF_SCHEDULED) AS TOTAL_PLANNED
```

And I have no idea what the (+) means in this line:

```
 WHERE ASP.ASP_SPACE_NM = MO.ASP_SPACE_NM (+)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's old school, Oracle specific LEFT JOIN syntax.  You want to replace it with:

```
CREATE VIEW PLANNED AS
   SELECT s.asp_space_nm,
          SUM(o.mo_tkr_total_off_scheduled) 'total_planned'
     FROM SPACE s
LEFT JOIN OBJECTIVE o ON o.asp_space_nm = s.asp_space_nm 
                     AND o.mo_msn_class_nm = 'EPIC'
 GROUP BY s.asp_space_nm
```

Reference:

- [Oracle LEFT JOIN](http://www.dba-oracle.com/tips_oracle_left_outer_join.htm)

Answer (score 2):

The `+` indicates an *(edit: left*) outer join.

And

```
SUM(MO.MO_TKR_TOTAL_OFF_SCHEDULED) "TOTAL_PLANNED"
```

is indeed very probably identical to

```
SUM(MO.MO_TKR_TOTAL_OFF_SCHEDULED) as "TOTAL_PLANNED"
```

If I recall correctly `as` is not really needed in PostgreSQL as well (although it makes it a lot more explicit in my view).

You could have a look at the following page on the Postgresql wiki for some more differences: [Oracle to Postgres conversion](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Oracle_to_Postgres_Conversion).